# Finite Field Linear Algebra Library for Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, linear-algebra, algebra, finite-field

I'm searching for a finite field linear algebra library for Haskell.

Something like [FFLAS-FFPACK](http://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Guillaume.Dumas/FFLAS/index.html) for Haskell would be great :-).

Of course, I checked [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.14.0.1), there seems to be some support for [arbitrary matrix element types](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.14.0.1/doc/html/Data-Packed-Matrix.html) but I couldn't find any finite field library which works with hmatrix. And surely I'd appreciate a performant solution :-)

In particular I want to be able to multiply <sub>p</sub><sup>n×1</sup> and <sub>p</sub><sup>1×m</sup> matrices (vectors) to <sub>p</sub><sup>n×m</sup> matrices.

Comment: As of version 0.17 hmatrix supports modular arithmetic with [type `Mod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.17.0.1/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Data.html#t:Mod).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be a binding to FFLAS/FFPACK, that represents the data in native Haskell types. However, I can't see that we have such a binding yet.

Related libraries that would be a good starting point:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vect
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/jalla
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blas

For getting started with array structures the vector tutorial isn't bad:

- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Vector_Tutorial

So, in summary, I think you might need to quickly whip up bindings to fflas, then expose them via hmatrix or vector.

Comment: Thanks, @Don, unfortunately I can't even find at C (not C++ with templates) library I could use to interface :-(. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718629/finite-field-linear-algebra-library-for-c-not-c