# Finite Field (Galois Field) Linear Algebra Library for C (not C++)

Tags: c, linear-algebra, ffi, finite-field

I'm searching for a [finite field/galois field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) exact linear algebra library for C (C++ is not acceptable because I need to be able to write a Haskell-binding to it and that's apparently [difficult with C++](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cxx_foreign_function_interface)).

I found libraries for like [FFLAS-FFPACK](http://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Guillaume.Dumas/FFLAS/) and [Givaro](http://givaro.forge.imag.fr/) but these are C++-template libraries :-(

In particular I want to be able to multiply <sub>p</sub><sup>n×1</sup> and <sub>p</sub><sup>1×m</sup> matrices (vectors) to <sub>p</sub><sup>n×m</sup> matrices.

So, does anyone know a C or "extern C" library that is suitable?

PS: Here's my [Haskell question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665850/finite-field-linear-algebra-library-for-haskell) about the same matter.

Comment: It's not hard to export a C++ library as a C library by just replacing method calls with functions that take the instance as the first parameter.

Comment: +1 for the subscript/superscript characters :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , don't templates make it harder?

Comment: You just have to instantiate the classes that you want.

Comment: Does the [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/) do what you need?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the GSL works on `double`s and I need exact linear algebra on finite fields (e.g. _3 = {0, 1, 2}; 2 + 2 = 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) is opensource, is written in C and it supports some basic linear algebra over finite field.

No warranties for specific suitability from me, of course - I'm not related to the development.