# Finite field and rational linear algebra in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, linear-algebra

Is there a Haskell package that can compute the reduced row-echelon form of a matrix, with entries from either the rationals, or a finite field of prime size? I am looking for something that will be comparable in speed to computer algebra packages such as Sage.

I have looked at [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) and [other modules](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.19.0.0/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra.html) but they appear to be focused on numerical analysis rather than linear algebra. The [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665850/finite-field-linear-algebra-library-for-haskell) suggests that the answer was a qualified 'no' six years ago.